# Sinch Verification Swift 3

Tags: swift3, sinch, sinch-verification

I have been converting my code to swift 3. I have an issue with since verification:

This is the code I have:

```
verification.initiate { (success:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
            //handle outcome
            if (success){
                print("successfully requested phone verification")
                //segue to next screen
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "xxx", sender: nil)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                self.buttonsEnable(true)
            }
}
```

Xcode is returning the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Bool, Error?) -> Void' to expected argument type '(InitiationResult, Error?) -> Void'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I have updated to the latest version of the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pretty much tells you what the problem is. The completion block has to be of type

```
(InitiationResult, Error?) -> Void
```

instead of

```
(Bool, Error?) -> Void
```

So you should be able to do:

```
verification.initiate { (result:InitiationResult, error:Error?) -> Void in
```

and then check the success with

```
if result.success { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't sure about how to check success vs. error