# Sms Verification with Sinch swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, sinch, nserror, sinch-verification

Hi Im using Sinch sms verification to sign up users in my app but after updating my code to swift 3 (and sinch sdk currently 2.0.3), Im getting the following error

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Bool, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Bool, Error?) -> Void'
```

I know that if I change NSError to Error , this error disappear

[Sinch Verification Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696776/sinch-verification-swift-3)

but I need to get the error code from the NSError to alert my user on what happened depend on this error

```
   if (result.success){
          //login user
         } else {
            if error!.code == 6 {
                   let msg = NSLocalizedString("This Phone Number is invalid",
                         comment: "This Phone Number is invalid pop up alert")
                   print(msg)
            }
   }
```

From Sinch Docs , Im suppose to use this NSError:

https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/ios/#swiftsdk

```
 let verification = SMSVerification(applicationKey:"<APP KEY>", phoneNumber: phoneNumberInE164)
    verification.initiate { (result: InitiationResult, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // handle outcome
    }
```

Is there a way to get the error.code from error:Error? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Swift 3 bridges all `NSError` from Objective C code to `Error` type(protocol). So in closure parameters you should use `Error` and convert it inside closure to `NSError` using `as`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let verification = SMSVerification(applicationKey:"<APP KEY>", phoneNumber: phoneNumberInE164)
    verification.initiate { (result: InitiationResult, error: Error?) -> Void in
        // handle outcome
        if (result.success){
          //login user
         } else if let error = error as? NSError, error.code == 6 {
            let msg = NSLocalizedString("This Phone Number is invalid",
                         comment: "This Phone Number is invalid pop up alert")
            print(msg)
         }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @zombie , if you have some piece of code for this second question it would be great : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120985/sinch-sms-verification-2-0-3-sdk-swift-3